# Time discretization of the (stochastic) Navier-Stokes equation

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, numerical-analysis-of-pde

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be nonnempty and open
- $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle:=\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_{L^2(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}$

I've found a thesis where the author is suggesting (see [Algorithm 3.1 on page 26](https://publikationen.uni-tuebingen.de/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10900/49705/pdf/diss_main_pub.pdf?sequence=1)) the scheme $$\langle u^n-u^{n-1},v\rangle+k\nu\sum_{i=1}^d\langle\nabla u^n,\nabla v\rangle+k\langle(u^n\cdot\nabla)u^n,v\rangle\color{red}{-k\langle p^n,\nabla\cdot v\rangle+\frac k2\langle(\nabla\cdot u^n)u^n,v\rangle}=k\langle f^n,v\rangle\tag1$$ for the time discretization of the (stochastic) Navier-Stokes equation (the stochastic forcing is omitted in $(1)$) $$u'-\nu\Delta u+(u\cdot\nabla)u+\nabla p=f+g(u)\dot W\tag2$$. Above $u^n=u(t_n)$, $p^n=p(t_n)$, $f^n=f(t_n)$ and $(t_n)_n$ is an equidistant partition of the time interval of size $k>0$.

> What is the idea behind the red terms in $(1)$?

Comment: The first term in red is obtained by integration by parts of the pressure term (multiplied by test function $v$ ) in 2.

Comment: The second terms is intended to enforce incompressibility of $u$

Comment: @PiyushGrover The first term is clear, but how does the second term enforce incompressibility? Instead of the second term, I had expected $$k\langle(u^n\cdot\nabla)u^n,v\rangle\;.$$ Why don't we use that? (And let me note that one obviously uses [this relation](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2158400/47771).)

Comment: That term is already present (third term in black) in 3.